# Why is the color attribute of .active not applied?

Tags: css, background-color, css-specificity

When having an active div for changing the appearance of the active menu item(using jquery), the background color is changed as expected (white to black), however the color attribute of the text (black to white) is not. Why? - and how can I fix this?

css

```
.menu {
    width: 475px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu ul {
    min-width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 23px 0 0 0;
}

.menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

/*selected tag changes appearance*/
.active {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*attributes of individual nav button*/
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 75px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #4a4a4a;
}

/*changes appearance of menu item on hover*/
.menu a:hover {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    -webkit-transition: color, background-color .4s; /* Safari */
    transition: color, background-color .4s;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu a').click(function() {
    $(".menu a").removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active")
    });
});
```

html

```
<div class="menu">
            <ul>            
                <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#5">5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu a').click(function() {
    $(".menu a").removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active")
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 475px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu ul {
  min-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 23px 0 0 0;
}
.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}
/*selected tag changes appearance*/

.active {
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
/*attributes of individual nav button*/

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}
/*changes appearance of menu item on hover*/

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition: color, background-color .4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: color, background-color .4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of CSS [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The selector `.menu a` is a more specific than just `.active` so it has priority on the `color`.  Try changing `.active` to `.menu a.active`.

Comment: Your suggested change doesn't work for me. Now, neither of both css attributes is applied...The argument makes total sense to me though!

Comment: I fixed it using the "!important" rule! not very elegant though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
/*selected tag changes appearance*/
.menu > ul > li > .active {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when I change it into this.. Could you guys show me a code snippet? :)